# Laravel 4 - Route to subdomain except www

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Currently I have a routing group to subdomains and another routing group to the main site, like this:

```php
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.mysite.dev'), function() {
    // Subdomain routes
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'SubdomainController@showHome'));
});

// Main
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PublicController@showHome'));
```

It's working fine so far for both 'mysite.dev' and for 'stuff.mysite.dev' or any other subdomain.
The problem is that it assumes 'www' (as in 'www.mysite.dev') as a subdomain and I need it to be interpreted as the main site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to itachi response, I came up with this:

```php
Route::pattern('subdomain', '^((?!www).)*$');
```

Adding this line to the top of routes.php, makes the 'subdomain' match anything except 'www'.

Final form:

```php
Route::pattern('subdomain', '^((?!www).)*$');

Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.mysite.dev'), function() {
    // Subdomain routes
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'SubdomainController@showHome'));
});

// Main site routes (works for mysite.dev and www.mysite.dev)
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PublicController@showHome'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::pattern('subdomain','dev|test|mobile'); <---- add your subdomains

Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.mysite.dev'), function() {
    // Subdomain routes
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'SubdomainController@showHome'));
});

// Main
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PublicController@showHome'));
```

just add the 1st line and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

1) You could use .htaccess redirect www to non-www

2) check http://laravel.com/docs/routing for Regular Expression constraints, so at the end of the route you add ->where('subdomain', '!www'); ( not tested )

Comment: I don't think I can use the where function in a group without 3rd party extensions.

Comment: Also, I don't really want to mess with .htaccess